# Translating view and viewpager's fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I have a little strange problem for me. I need to translate view which is located over a viewpager on recyclerview scroll. RecyclerView is located in fragment and fragments are located in viewpager. When I scroll recyclerview in fragment and want to translate View which is located over viewpager my problem occurs. ViewPager is moving up to fill space left by translated view, but fragments aren't. Because of it I can see space empty space on viewpager. I checked it by setting viewpager background and i saw that viewpager actually resized to match container but fragments remained still. Any ideas how to force it to works as it should be? This code works perfectly when recyclerview and view which I want to resize are on same fragment.

Issue look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVpvF.png

Layout look like this 
ViewPagerFragment

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clipToPadding="false">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/subcategory_fragment_recycle_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Layout with Viewpager

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/fragment_category_sliding_tab_layout">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/fragment_category_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="100dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scrollTemp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:text="TEMP"
        android:textSize="40dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

For detecting scrollevents and triggering show/hide of temp view I am using basically this HidingScrollListener https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/28/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part2%29/. As I said it works perfectly when recyclerview and view which I want to scroll are on same fragment.